# java Regex Date Validation for 1900-9999 in yyyyMMdd

Tags: java, regex

How to convert the regex from

```
^((19|20)\\d\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])? for 1900-2099
```

The above one works perfectly,just want change for date formats 1900-9999.So go for below one.

I tried like this it is not working

```
^(([19-99])\\d\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])? for 1900-9999
```

What is wrong please guide me resolve this.

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output to make things more clear

Comment: `^(19\d{2}|[2-9]\d{3})$`

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag Input date(yyyyMMdd) is 19000130-99991231

Comment: As pshemos says, this is probably not the best application for a regex.  Just checking the value range will be easier and maintainable.

Comment: won't it be more maintainable to convert into a Date and then compare it with the range ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't even use regex to validate integers range (it is maintenance hell later, just like you are having now). Instead parse your string to something more accurate like Date or integer and use `<` `<=` `>` `>=` operators.

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(yourYear)
if (year >= 1900 && year <= 9999){
    //do your job here
}
```

---

But if you don't have a choice and you must do it with regex you can try with
`19\\d\\d|[2-9]\\d\\d\\d` which you can visualize as

```
19xx  <->    1    9 \\d \\d
2xxx  <-> [2-9] \\d \\d \\d
3xxx  <-> [2-9] \\d \\d \\d
4xxx  <-> [2-9] \\d \\d \\d
5xxx  <-> [2-9] \\d \\d \\d
6xxx  <-> [2-9] \\d \\d \\d
7xxx  <-> [2-9] \\d \\d \\d
8xxx  <-> [2-9] \\d \\d \\d
9xxx  <-> [2-9] \\d \\d \\d
```

Little shorter regex could be `19\\d{2}|[2-9]\\d{3}`.

Comment: You made my day

Answer (score 0):

`[19-99]` is a wrong usage of the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) operators `[..]`. This part would match *one* character out of the set of `1`, `9` to `9`, or `9` (i.e., only `1` or `9`).

I have no idea why the top ("working") expression is so complicated. You can just use

```
\b(19|20)\d\d\b
```

for 1900-2099, and

```
\b19\d\d\b
```

for 1900-1999. Double-escape mybackslashes for use in a Java string.

(... After another question change)

and for 1900-9999, simply use

```
\b(19|[2-9]9)\d{2}\b
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , not for 1900-1999 but for 1900-9999.?

Answer (score 0):

The expression could look like this:

```
^(19|[2-9]\\d)\\d{2}$
```

For explanation:

`^` : start of string
`(19|[2-9]\\d)` : either the value `19` or values `20` to `99`
`\\d{2}` : values `00` to `99`
`$` : end of string